# customize Emacs speedbar file indicators

Tags: emacs

Is there any way top change the unknown file indicators for speedbar ? I would prefer not to see a bunch of "?"s in there... also I don't care about expanding files in speedbar, I would need it to act more or less like a file tree viewer (like NERTree in vim or the drawer in TextMate)

Thanks
Cezar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try 'M-: (speedbar-image-dump)' or 'M-: (ezimage-image-dump)'. if the icon (or text equivalent - [?] seems to refer to 'ezimage-page') is there then search for the relevant .xpm file under your emacs (or cedet) install path and edit it.

editing is easy, there's an icon-mode in emacs which shows you the final icon, but by switching to text-mode you can see that the structure is simply a grid of characters (usually '+' or '.') with colours mapped to them, #RRGGBB html/hex or standard emacs colours are supported.

remember to 'M-: (clear-image-cache)'

cheers.